# Remove last or trailling slash from the site which is hosted on nginx server

Tags: nginx, http-redirect

I am having Drupal site with two languages English and French. Now there is a abbreviations for both the languages in my site.

For Example,

```
# for English 
http://www.sitename.com/en
```

and

```
# for French
http://www.sitename.com/fr
```

If someone visits the URL `http://www.sitename.com/fr/`, then the user should be redirect to the URL `http://www.sitename.com/fr` (no trailing "/").

However the user remains on the URL `http://www.sitename.com/fr/` (with leading "/" that the user typed).

NOTE: I am using `nginx` web server. So `.htaccess` will not be of any help.

I am facing this problem since long.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

in your `server{}` block.